# AngularJS directive $watch two-way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to distinguish between internal change and an external change with a two-way data-bound attribute (`'='`).

In other words: I don't want to `$watch` to fire on the value if the change was internal (i.e. the scope variable was changed in the controller or in the link function).

Here some code that illustrates my problem:

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">         
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <input ng-model="value"/>
     <mydemo value="value"></mydemo>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
app.directive('mydemo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: "="
    },
    template: "<div id='mydiv'>Click to change value attribute</div> Value:{{value}}",

    link: function (scope, elm) 
    {      
      scope.$watch('value', function (newVal) {
      //Don't listen if the change came from changeValue function
      //Listen if the change came from input element 
      });
      // Otherwise keep any model syncing here.

      var changeValue = function()
      {
        scope.$apply(function ()
        {
          scope.value = " from changeValue function";
        });
      }

      elm.bind('click', changeValue);
    }
  }
})
```

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/B7hT5/11/

Any idea who can I distinguish?

Answer (score 8):

There's no option to distinguish between these two events, so you'll have to implement that behaviour yourself.

I would do it by setting a flag whenever you make a change "internally", then checking for it in the watch.

For example:

```
link: function (scope, elm){      

  var internal = false;

  scope.$watch('value', function (newVal) {
    if(internal) return internal = false;
    // Whatever code you want to run on external change goes here.
    console.log(newVal);
  });

  var changeValue = function(){
    scope.$apply(function (){
      internal = true; // flag internal changes
      scope.value = " from changeValue function";                              
    });
  }

  elm.bind('click', changeValue);
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7hT5/12/).

Your alternative (more complex) approach, is creating a custom directive that uses the `ngModel` API. That distinguishes between DOM -> Model (external) and Model -> DOM (internal) changes. I don't think it's necessary here, though.