# in directive, how I know if change come from outside

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

when I write directive and watch on some attribute. how I can mention if the change come from outside or is me doing the change.

for exmaple :

```
.directive('amInput',function(){
    return {
        scope:{
            selectAll:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr ){
            scope.$watch('selectAll', function (nv, ol) {
                 doSomthing();
            });

            // after some code run 
            doSomthing();
            scope.selectAll = true;



        }
    }

})
```

so in the example something append and I run `doSomthing()` and update the flag to true. in next cycle angular recognize that the flag changed and run `doSomthing()` again !!

how I prevent that ?

Comment: there isn't enough code here to provide context to what is going on.  why wouldn't you just change the variable, and let the watch run the function? why do you need to run the function before toggling the variable?

Comment: I find the same qustion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553167/angularjs-directive-watch-two-way-binding) .  
I used there solution but maybe there is a better way